# Typescript - call child method from parent class

Tags: typescript

I am trying to call the child method from the abstract parent class in typescript. But i am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.activateMultiselect is not a function

How would I implement this without error?

Here is the code:

```
interface iGetAreas {
    _areasList: Array<string>;
    _areas: KnockoutObservableArray<string>;
    _selectedArea: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    getAreas(geonameId: string);
    activateMultiselect();
}

abstract class AreaGetter implements iGetAreas {
    _areasList = [];
    _areas = ko.observableArray([]);
    _selectedArea = ko.observable('');

    abstract activateMultiselect();

    getAreas(geonameId){
        var self = this;
        self._areasList = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: `http://api.geonames.org/children?geonameId=${geonameId}&username=elion`
        }).then(function(allAreasXML) {
            var allAreasJSON = xml2json(allAreasXML);
            var allAreas = JSON.parse(allAreasJSON);
            if(allAreas.geonames.length) {
                for (var index = 1; index < allAreas.geonames.length - 1; index++) {
                self._areasList.push(allAreas.geonames[index].geoname);
                }
            } else {
                if(allAreas.geonames) {
                    self._areasList.push(allAreas.geonames.geoname);
                }
            }
            self._areas(self._areasList);
            this.activateMultiselect();
        });
    }
}

class RegionGetter extends AreaGetter {
    activateMultiselect() {
        $("#region-select").multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '100%',
            buttonContainer: '<div style="height: 64px;" />',
            buttonClass: 'none',
            onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
                alert('Changed region option ' + $(option).val() + '.');
            }
        });
    }
}

class TownGetter extends AreaGetter {
    activateMultiselect() {
        $("#town-select").multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '100%',
            buttonContainer: '<div style="height: 64px;" />',
            buttonClass: 'none',
            onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
                alert('Changed town option ' + $(option).val() + '.');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: this.activateMultiselect is not a function

The error is not because of `child` classes not having the function. Its because you have the wrong `this` in:

```
this.activateMultiselect();
```

Fix :

```
self.activateMultiselect();
```

## More

PS: recommend using an `arrow` function. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to an arrow function, and also the `.then(` to an arrow function. It seems slower performing but I'm not sure if it's all in my head.

Comment: All in the head. Having `self` there means that there can be no pref difference  Also code that works can feel slower than code that crashes `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)